# Magento Layered Navigation "You cannot define a correlation name 'mycustomattribute' more than once "

Tags: magento, filter, navigation

I'm using Magento's layered navigation with my custom attributes and price. If I filter by price it works; but when filtering by my custom attributes it shows:

> You cannot define a correlation name 'mycustomattribute' more than once

trace:

```
#0 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281):
Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'metal_idx.entit...', Array, NULL)
#1 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(336):          Varien_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'metal_idx.entit...', Array, NULL)
#2 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(315): Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'metal_idx.entit...', Array, NULL)
#3 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(70): Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'metal_idx.entit...', Array)
#4 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(94): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->applyFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute), '49')
#5  /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(91): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute->apply(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute))
#6 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(73): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initFilter()
#7 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(136): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->init()
#8 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
#9 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#10 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')
#11 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')
#12 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#13 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):  Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#14 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#15 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(146): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#16 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#17 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#18 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App-    >run(Array)
#21 /home/coloresh/public_html/ColoreSG.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is because `catalog/layer_view module` was called twice.
You can search `type="catalog/layer_view"` through your xml files. Remove the block you don't need. Or change the type to another class.

Comment: FYI: In my case, my class had a custom `_getCount()` method which was doing all of the same filtering logic as `apply()` so that I could provide value counts in the layered navigation menu. This works when applying any other filter (or no filter) but as soon as I applied my custom filter, the logic was duplicated. The block didn't have to be duplicated to run into this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had `<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>`
twice.
Deleted one line and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to get rid of the block that was `type="catalog/layer_view"` from local.xml and catalog.xml and put my modified `type="catalog/layer_view"` block.

Be sure there is only one block that contains `type="catalog/layer_view"`.

Answer (score 0):

For me Dubbo's answer was right, but more specifically I found out that Magento Enterprise touches the catalog_category_layered xml node in the enterprise_search.xml file

Comment: I'm using enterprise as well, and running into a similar issue with my custom product attribute **Colors**. Any chance you can provide details on the steps you took to resolve the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fix can be found here: http://aceph.tumblr.com/post/21851233473/magento-you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name

Answer (score 0):

This causes the same problem.
-adding the same attribute to the sort twice when building a collection:

```
...
    ->addAttributeToSort('color', 'asc')
    ->addAttributeToSort('color', 'asc');
```

NOTE: calling setCollection($this->getMyCollection); on the template caused my error,
because 'color' was already added to the sort order as the default sort order.

SOLUTION:a quick way to fix this is to remove the default sort order from the request after obtain the value:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('order','');
```

otherwise extend the Block and override the setCollection() method for your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

For any of you who are looking for a way to solve this issue in Magento Enterprise Edition, check if your catalog.xml or local.xml template has catalog search layered navigation. If you do have it, override the search.xml in your current theme from the enterprise theme and empty all the block reference in it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on an Enterprise build, so posting for anyone else that needs it - turned out I had to use the following in order to get it to work:

```
<remove name="enterprisecatalog.leftnav" />
```