# Large list of search filter errors encountered

Tags: mysql, magento, php

I'm having an issue with the search filter, for some reason when I select the filters, I get a page with error codes all over:

> **There has been an error processing your request
>   You cannot define a correlation name color_idx more than once**
>
> Trace:
>
> #0 /home/oembarga/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'color_idx.entit...',
>   Array, NULL)
>
> #1 /home/oembarga/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(336): Varien_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'color_idx.entit...',
>   Array, NULL)
>
> #2 /home/oembarga/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(315): Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'color_idx.entit...', Array, NULL)
>
> #3 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(70):
>   Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'color_idx.entit...', Array)
>
> #4 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(94): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->applyFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute),
>   '56')
>
> #5 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(91):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute->apply(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http),
>   Object(Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute))
>
> #6 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(73):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initFilter()
>
> #7 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(136):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->init()
>
> #8 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
>
> #9 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Codnitive_Extifcon_Model_Core_Layout))
>
> #10 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/layer_v...',
>   'catalog.leftnav')
>
> #11 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/layer_v...',
>   'catalog.leftnav')
>
> #12 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>
> #13 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>
> #14 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>
> #15 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>
> #16 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Unirgy_DropshipMicrositePro_IndexController),
>   'default-microsi...')
>
> #17 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/community/Unirgy/DropshipMicrositePro/controllers/IndexController.php(33):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Unirgy_DropshipMicrositePro_IndexController), 'default-microsi...')
>
> #18 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Unirgy_DropshipMicrositePro_IndexController->landingPageAction()
>
> #19 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('landingPage')
>
> #20 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> #21 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> #22 /home/oembarga/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> #23 /home/oembarga/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> #24 {main}

Comment: By referring to search filters, are you referencing Catalog Search or the traditional left side navigation?

Comment: It looks like you apply a filter twice somehow. Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524017/magento-layered-navigation-you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name-mycustomattrib).